# Are there any words which contain a double vowel, a double consonant, and also is 4 letters?

Tags: vocabulary

By "double", I mean the same letter twice. There are many double consonant 4 letter words. There are also many double vowel 4 letters words. However, are there any which include all three of these restrictions, specifically, in the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Comment: By "double" I would assume that you mean the same letter twice?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for https://puzzles.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Cascabel By "double", I mean the same letter twice. As for the SWR tag, no other tag really fit.

Comment: @Hot Yes, I do mean the same letter twice

Comment: It would be tedious but feasible to research this yourself.  There are 21 consonants and 5 vowels.  That is 105 combinations, but, taking into account that either consonants or vowels may be first there are 210 potential words you must research.

Comment: Using a regexp search on unix /usr/share/dict/words, there are none. There are many that end in a double vowel, 6 that begin with a double vowel (eely, oofy, oons, oont, oord, oozy, all very questionable words), and none that begin or end in double consonants. Double consonants only exist in English orthography from two words that have come to be spelled without a space, and since there are no single consonant words in English, a double consonant at the end or beginning of a word is impossible.

Comment: If you relax your conditions and allow VCCV or CVVC, then you get acca
adda
affa
amma
anna
atta
elle
immi
otto, or boob
deed
keek
maam
noon
peep
poop
teet
toot, also many of these are questionably acceptable words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trivia, and suitable for puzzles.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting once again to close this question as off-topic because it is about trivia, and suitable for puzzles.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but probably not in Merriam Webster. Looking at the OED, there's *ooff*:

> *Scottish. Obsolete. rare.*
>
> *intransitive*. To move (about) in a stupid manner.

If it doesn't need to have consonants, the OED also lists *ooaa* ("The Kauai oo, Moho braccatus, which is believed to have become extinct in the late 1980s"). If it doesn't need to have vowels that might be pushing the definition of word, but the OED has *XXXX* ("Used as a humorously euphemistic substitute for a four-letter swear word").

If CVCV/VCVC/CVVC/VCCV is allowed, then I'm using the power of regex with `grep -i -E '^(.)(.)(\1\2|\2\1)$' /usr/share/dict/words`, which gets me:

> acca, adad, adda, affa, amma, anan, anna, arar, atta, baba, bibi, bobo, boob, coco, dada, deed, dodo, elle, eyey, gogo, gugu, immi, juju, kaka, keek, kiki, koko, kuku, lulu, maam, momo, nana, noon, otto, papa, peep, pipi, poop, ruru, sasa, sisi, soso, susu, teet, tete, titi, toot, toto, tutu, wawa, yaya

Comment: SEES is another extremely common word that is not in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Fun question. 
None, according to Wolfram Alpha:

- aa__ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=aa__)
- __aa (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=__aa)
- ee__ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ee__)
- __ee (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=__ee)

etc.

The only result that matches your constraint of double vowel and double consonant is "xxii", but it doesn't qualify as a word :-)